# How can I dynamically get the set of classes from the current python module?

Tags: python, reflection, metaprogramming

I have a python module that defines a number of classes:

```
class A(object):
    def __call__(self):
        print "ran a"

class B(object):
    def __call__(self):
        print "ran b"

class C(object):
    def __call__(self):
        print "ran c"
```

From within the module, how might I add an attribute that gives me all of the classes?

dir() gives me the names of everything from within my module, but I can't seem to figure out how to go from the name of a class to the class itself from *within* the module.

From outside of the module, I can simply use `getattr(mod, 'A')`, but I don't have a `self` kind of module from within the module itself.

This seems pretty obvious.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import sys
getattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'A')
```

Comment: Ah, sys.modules is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much.  :)

Answer (score 6):

You can smash this into one for statement, but that'd have messy code duplication.

```
import sys
import types
this_module = sys.modules[__name__]
[x for x in
    [getattr(this_module, x) for x in dir(this_module)]
    if type(x) == types.ClassType]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I have a specific type of filter I'll need to run the stuff through, but it's really sys.modules that was the key.

Answer (score 3):

```
classes = [x for x in globals().values() if isinstance(x, type)]
```